# use linq with object that contains nested IEnumerable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an object called `ExportedPhotoresult exportedPhotoresult` which contains an object `Article article`. This object of type article contains another object `IEnumrable<ArticleDescriptionDetails> DescriptionDetails`. This last one has three property  `string Code`, `string Value` and `bool Hidden`.

I'm tring to write a method to return an `exportedPhotoresult`if `DescriptionDetails.Code` is not empty or null, and `DescriptionDetails.Code`is equals to 'hidden'

I write this code

```
foreach (var dd in exportedPhotoresult.Article.DescriptionDetails)
     if (!dd.Code.isNullorEmpty() && dd.Hidden == hidden)
        return exportedPhotoresult;
return null
```

Is it possibile re-write this code using Linq ?

I tried in this way

```
return exportedPhotoresult.Article.DescriptionDetails
        .Where( x=> 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Code) && 
            x.Hidden == hidden
         )
```

But it's obviusly wrong.

Comment: The only difference in your code from original is you are missing at end .FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if `Any()` element matches the expression;

```cs
return (exportedPhotoresult.Article.DescriptionDetails
        .Any(dd => !string.isNullorEmpty(dd.Code) && dd.Hidden == hidden))
    ? exportedPhotoresult
    : null;
```

But since you are returning the parent object, I wouldn't try to reduce the expression any futher.

Comment: so in your opinion is better iterate in the classical way ? However thanks for your answer

Comment: I mean you *could* `Where(...).Select( dd => exportedPhotoresult).FirstOrDefault()`, but that seems more complex.